# validating using onblur and onsubmit

Tags: javascript, forms, input, onsubmit, onblur

I would like to know how to validate a form when I use the onblur handler and the onsubmit handler at the same time. I've tried to do it and it goes straight to the submit page without displaying an error message.

Because I also have radio buttons and checkboxes, how do I validate these if the user didn't click the radio button and exclude the checkbox from validation.

Thank You

```js
function IsNotBlank(tf, tfHelp) {

    var value = tf.value;

    if (value == " ") {
        tf.className = "invalid ";
        tfHelp.innerHTML = "This field can 't be blank.";
        return false;
    } else {
        tf.className = "valid";
        tfHelp.innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
}

function CheckLetters(tf, tfHelp) {

    //check empty field from previous function.
    var NotEmpty = IsNotBlank(tf, tfHelp);

    if (NotEmpty == false) {
        return false;
    }

    //assign field value
    var value = tf.value;


    //check if there is numbers.
    var regex = new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z]{5,18}$/);

    var testResult = regex.test(value);
    if (testResult == false) {
        tf.className = "invalid";
        tfHelp.innerHTML = "Use letters only and lengths must be between 5 and 18 characters.";
        return false;
    } else {
        tf.className = "valid";
        tfHelp.innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
}

function CheckPhNumber(tf, tfHelp) {

    //check empty field
    var NotEmpty = IsNotBlank(tf, tfHelp);
    if (NotEmpty == false)
        return false;


    var value = tf.value;
    //validate phone number.
    var regex = /^\d{8,10}$/;
    var testResult = regex.test(value);
    //logic
    if (testResult == false) {
        tf.className = "invalid";
        tfHelp.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid phone number.";
        return false;
    } else {
        tf.ClassName = "valid";
        tfHelp.innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
}

function CheckEmail(tf, tfHelp) {

    //check empty field
    NotEmpty = IsNotBlank(tf, tfHelp);
    if (NotEmpty == false) {
        return false;
    }



    var value = tf.value;
    //validate email address

    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;

    var testResult = regex.test(value);

    //logic
    if (testResult == false) {
        tf.className = "invalid";
        tfHelp.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email address.";
        return false;
    } else {
        tf.className = "valid";
        tfHelp.innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
}

function CheckPostCode(tf, tfHelp) {

    //check empty field
    var NotEmpty = IsNotBlank(tf, tfHelp);
    if (NotEmpty == false)
        return false;


    var value = tf.value;
    //validate postcode.
    var regex = /^\d{4}$/;
    var testResult = regex.test(value);
    //logic
    if (testResult == false) {
        tf.className = "invalid";
        tfHelp.innerHTML = "Please enter a 4 digit post code.";
        return false;
    } else {
        tf.ClassName = "valid";
        tfHelp.innerHTML = "";
        return false;
    }
}

function ValidateForm(form) {

    var formCheck = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
        var e = form.elements[i];
        //alert(form.elements[i]);
        if (e.onblur) {
            // alert(e.onblur());
            formCheck = e.onblur() && formCheck;
        }
    }
    return formCheck;
}

function ResetForm(form) {
    //select input elements and change color back to default
    var arrayInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayInputs.length; i++) {
        arrayInputs[i].className = "valid";
    }

    //clear text on span elements
    var arraySpans = document.getElementsByTagName('span ');
    for (var i = 0; i < arraySpans.length; i++) {
        arraySpans[i].innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="submit.html" onreset="ResetForm()" onsubmit="ValidateForm(this);">
    <div>
        <label for="fname" class="label">First Name:</label>
        <input class="valid" type="text" id="txtFname" onblur="return CheckLetters(this, txtFnameHelp);" />
        <span id="txtFnameHelp"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="one">
        <label for="lname" class="label">Last Name:</label>
        <input class="valid" name="lname" id="txtLname" type="text" onblur="return CheckLetters(this, txtLnameHelp);" />
        <span id="txtLnameHelp"></span>

    </div>
    <div class="one">
        <label class="label" for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
        <input class="one" id="txtPhone" type="text" onblur="CheckPhNumber(this, txtPhoneHelp);"><br>
        <span id="txtPhoneHelp"></span>

    </div>
    <div class="one">
        <label for="email" class="label">Email Address:</label>
        <input class="valid" id="txtEmail" type="text" onblur="CheckEmail(this, txtEmailHelp)">
        <span id="txtEmailHelp"></span><br>
    </div>
    <div class="one">
        <label class="label">Post Code:</label>
        <input id="txtPostcode" type="text" onblur="CheckPostCode(this, txtPostCodeHelp);"> <br>
        <span id="txtPostCodeHelp"></span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <label>Prefered Contact Method</label><br>
    </div>
    <div class="one">
        </--<input type="radio" name="contact" value="email">Email
        </-- <input type="radio" name="contact" value="phone">Phone
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="one">
        <label>Your Message:</label><br />
        <textarea id="txtMessage" rows="8" cols="40" onblur="IsNotBlank(this, txtMessageHelp)">Your Message</textarea>
        <span id="txtMessageHelp"></span>
        <br><br>
    </div>
    </--<input class="one" type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="subscribe">I would like to subscribe to the newsletter <br>
    <div>
        <input class="one" type="submit" value="Send">
        <input class="one " type="Reset " value="Clear">
        <br><br>
    </div>

</form>
```

Note that these type of JavaScript code can only be debugged using Microsoft Visual Studio for some reason and would not work on using legacy text editors.

Comment: Use required attribute which is HTML5 default validator, if your requirement is to show only required field validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below concept to perform the both action and use `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'function(e) {})` to check the validation

```js
var error_user_name = false;

function checkpw(ele, e){
  var user_name = document.forms["joinform"]["user_name"].value;

  if (user_name == null || user_name == "") {
    text = "UserName : Required";
    document.getElementById("errormsg4").innerHTML = text;
    error_user_name = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("errormsg4").innerHTML = "";
    error_user_name = true;
  }
}

function submitall(ele, e) {
  checkpw();

  if(error_user_name == false) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    console.log('form submitted');
  }
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) { document.getElementById('user_name').addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
    checkpw(this, e);
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (document.activeElement.id == 'join') {
        document.activeElement.click();
      }
    }, 10);
  }, false);
  document.getElementById('joinform').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    submitall(this, e);
  }, false);
});
```

```html
<form id="joinform" method="post" name="joinform" action="#hello">
    <h2>Join</h2>

    <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" placeholder="User_Name"/>
    <div class ="errormsg" id ="errormsg4"></div><br>
    <input type="submit" name="join" id="join" value="Submit"   ><br><br>

</form>
```